# Python: Run multiple instances at once with different value set for each instance

Tags: python

I'm starting up in Python and have done a lot of programming in the past in VB.  Python seems much easier to work with and far more powerful.  I'm in the process of ditching Windows altogether and have quite a few VB programs I've written and want to use them on Linux without having to touch anything that involves Windows.

I'm trying to take one of my VB programs and convert it to Python.  I think I pretty much have.

One thing I never could find a way to do in VB was to use Program 1, a calling program, to call Program 2 and run in it multiple times.  I had a program that would search a website looking for new updated material, everything was updated numerically(1234567890_1.mp3, for example).  Not every value was used and I would have to search to find which files existed and which didn't.  Typically the site would run through around 100,000 possible files a day with only 2-3 files actually being used each day.  I had the program set up to search 10,000 files and if it found a file that existed it downloaded it and then moved to the next possible file and tested it.  I would run this program, simultaneously 10 times and have each program set up to search a separate 10,000 file block.  I always wanted to set up it so I could have a calling program that would have the user set the Main Block(1234) and the Secondary Block(5) with the Secondary Block possibly being a range of values.  The calling program then would start up 10 separate programs(6, err 0-9 in reality) and would use Main Block and Secondary Block as the values to set up the call for each of the 10 Program 2s.  When each one of the 10 programs got called, all running at the same time, they would be called with the appropriate search locations so they would be searching the website to find what new files had been added throughout the previous day.  It would only take 35-45 minutes to complete each day versus multiple hours if I ran through everything in one long continuous program.

I think I could do this with Python using a Program 1(set) and Program 2(read) .txt file.  I'm not sure if I would run into problems possibly with changing the set value before Program 2 could have read the value and started using it.  I think I would have a to add a pause into the program to play it safe... I'm not really sure.

Is there another way I could pass a value from Program 1 to Program 2 to accomplish the task I'm looking to accomplish?

Comment: Start experimenting, than ask if you've got a problem. Perhaps it would take longer for your question to be answered than if you try it yourself.. :)

Comment: I'd recommend [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Your "Program 1" becomes a celery task which completes and starts the "Program 2" task. You'll get scheduling, async thread management, and a whole host of other benefits for free.

Answer (score 0):

It seems simple enough to have a master class (a block as you would call it), that would contain all of the different threads/classes in a list. Communication wise, there could simply be a communication stucture like so:

```
Thread <--> Master <--> Thread
```

or

```
Thread <---> Thread <---> Thread
```

The latter would look more like a web structure.

The first option would probably be a bit more complicated since you have a "middle man". However, this does allow for mass communication. Also all that would need to passed to the other classes is the class Master, or a function that will provide communication

The second option allows for direct communication between threads. So if there is two threads that need to work together a lot, and you don't want to have to deal with other threads possibly interacting to the commands, then the second option is the best. However, the list of classes would have to be sent to the function.

Either way you are going to need to have a Master thread at the central of communication (for simplicity reasons). Otherwise you could get into sock and file stuff, but the other one is faster, more efficient, and is less likely to cause headaches.

Hopefully you understood what I was saying. It is all theoretical, but I have used similar  systems in my programs.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this; probably the simplest is to use `os.spawnv` to run multiple instances of Program2 and pass the appropriate values to each, ie

```
import os
import sys

def main(urlfmt, start, end, threads):
    start, end, threads = int(start), int(end), int(threads)
    per_thread = (end - start + 1) // threads
    for i in range(threads):
        s = str(start + i*per_thread)
        e = str(min(s + per_thread - 1, end))
        outfile = 'output{}.txt'.format(i+1)
        os.spawnv(os.P_NOWAIT, 'program2.exe', [urlfmt, s, e, outfile])

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print('Usage: web_search.py urlformat start end threads')
    else:
        main(*(sys.argv))
```